# Lower bound of infimum of sum of two monotone decreasing functions

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, maxima-minima

Consider on $(0, 1]$ the function $f$ defined by $$f(w)=\inf_{\overset{uv=w\leq1}{u>0,~0<v\leq\frac{1}{2}}}(g(u)+h(v)),$$ where $$g(u)= \left\{ \begin{array}{lc} (\log u)^{\delta},& u\geq 2, \\cu^{-1},& u<2\end{array}\right.$$ where $\delta<0$ and $c$ is a constant chosen so that $g$ is continuous, and $$h(v)=v^{p-1},\quad 0\leq v\leq \frac{1}{2},$$ where $p\in (0, 1)$. Note that both $g$ and $h$ are monotone decreasing.

> Is there a simple way to get a lower bound for $f$ (up to constant)?

I am looking for a sharper lower bound than just a constant, that means that $f(w)\to \infty$ as $w\to 0$.

Is it true that the infimum is attained when $f$ and $g$ are comparable?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do we need to look at $g$ when $u>2$ ? We are minimizing on $uv\leq u/2\leq 1$ only if $u\leq 2$.

Answer (score 1):

The problem reduces to finding

$$\inf_{\substack{0<w\leq 1\\0<v\leq \frac{1}{2}}}(\frac{c v}{w}+v^{p-1})=
\inf_{0<v\leq \frac{1}{2}}(c v+v^{p-1})$$

Comment: I am looking for a sharper lower bound than just a constant. I hope that $f(w)\to \infty$ as $w\to 0$.

Comment: Well, the supremum is $+\infty$..